# Undeployment fails for GWT application in tomcat 7

Tags: gwt, deployment, tomcat7

I am using the cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.0 to do redeployments of my GWT 2.4.0 based web application to Apache Tomcat 7.0.25 1.6.0_30-b12 Sun Microsystems Inc. Windows Server 2008 R2 6.1 amd64).

The initial deployment works fine. I immediately try to undeploy the application using the tomcat manager when I receive the following error message:

```
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\apache-tomcat7\webapps\mywebapp]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.
```

From tomcat the war file and most of the unzipped web application files have been successfully removed. But it fails to delete two libraries from mywebapp\WEB-INF\lib:

- gwt-user-2.4.0
- servlet-api-2.3

When I now wait half a minute and trigger the undeploy again, it works.

Did anybody experience the same or a similar behavior?
I already tried to debug using PSI Probe for Tomcat but that didn't really give me any insights. What could I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both files shouldn't be deployed in the first palce. First `gwt-user-2.4.0` is the complete gwt jar file. For deployment only the server specific version needs to be deployed: `gwt-servlet-2.4.0.jar`. The `servlet-api-2.3` is already available in the tomcat lib directory. So you should set both files to provided and if you not yet have the gwt-servlet jar file, add that file to you dependencies.

Comment: That fixed it! Indeed my dependency configuration was wrong. I corrected it by setting gwt-user as provided, gwt-servlet to compile and I removed the servlet-api dependency, which was unnecessarily inherited. Thanks Hilbrand!